# Handling all files in windows7

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine

I'm using Windows 7 at my home. I have a number of personal files. I want to share the files with my friends but they should not be able to modify or delete the files on my PC. Please guide me clearly in step wise to get my work done successfully without any issues.

Comment: What does this have to do with virtual machines?

Answer (score 3):

Simply Right Click the folder and click on `Properties`. In the `Sharing` tab click on Share. Then Select Everyone from the drop down menu. Then click on add. Under the `Permission Level` select the Level to Read.

They won't be able to modify or delete any files within that folder

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on your folder or hard disk
2. Sharing options -> Advanced share
3. Activate checkbox and click "Permisions"
4. Select the user who connects remotely and give it only "Read" permission.
5. Apply all.